# omegle lxml scrape not working

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

So I'm performing a scrape of omegle trying to scrape the users online.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="onlinecount">
    <strong>    
        30,000+    
    </strong>    
</div>
```

Now I would presume that using LXML it would be `//div[@id="onlinecount"]` to scrape any text within the , I want to get the numbers from the  tags, but when I try to scrape this, I just end up with an empty list

Here's my relevant code:

```
print "\n Grabbing users online now from",self.website
site = requests.get(self.website)
tree = html.fromstring(site.text)
users = tree.xpath('//div[@id="onlinecount"]')
```

Note that the self.website variable is just http://www.omegle.com

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Note I can scrape other parts just not the number of online users.

I ended up using a different set of code which I learned from a friend.
Here's my full code for anyone interested.
http://pastebin.com/u1kTLZtJ

Comment: I cannot get the source from where I am, but maybe the HTML code is not perfect XML. In this case, lxml may not be able to parse the tree properly. BeautifulSoup comes to the rescue in that case. Just my two cents :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send a GET request to "http://www.omegle.com" using requests python module,what I observed is that there is no "onlinecount" in site.text. The reason is that part gets rendered by a javascript. You should use a library that is able to execute the javascript and give you the final html source that is rendered in a browser. One such third party library is Selenium http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/. The only downside is that it opens a real web browser.

Below is a working code using selenium and an attached screenshot:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://www.omegle.com")
element = browser.find_element_by_id("onlinecount")
onlinecount = element.find_element_by_tag_name("strong")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use GET method on this http://front1.omegle.com/status

that will return the count of online users and other details in JSON form

Answer (score 0):

I have done a bit of looking at this and that particular part of the page is not XML but Javascript.

Here is the source (this is what the requests library is returning in your program)

```
        <div id="onlinecount"></div>
        <script>
        if (IS_MOBILE) {
            $('sharebuttons').dispose();
            $('onlinecount').dispose();
        }
        </script>
        </div>
```

As you can see, in lxml's eyes there is nothing but a script in the onlinecount div.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Praveen.

If you want to avoid launching a visible browser, you could use PhantomJS *which also has a selenium driver* :

http://phantomjs.org/

*PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API*

Instead of selenium scripts, you could also write PhantomJS js scripts (but I assume you prefer to stay in Python env ;))